# Region of Interest OpenJPEG

Tags: compression, jpeg, jpeg2000

I'm trying to compress a jpeg2000 image, but I need one region to be lossless. 
I've read in a few discussions that OpenJPEG implements a "window of interest" encoding, which solves my problem.

However, I can't find any documentation on how to use it.

I have also tried glymur, which should be simpler than using OpenJPEG directly. There seems to be some part of the code that mentions ROI but it's not very clear how it works.

How can I encode a jpeg2000 and have a region of interest that is not compressed?

Comment: OpenJPEG does not support ROI (they have something they call ROI, but it's not a ROI in the sense of a square region). Use Kakadu library instead. However, I suspect you are not looking for ROI. You are probably looking for compound documents (aka JPM; Part 6 of the standard). In JPM, multiple images can be combined into a single compound image, in your case, one compressed loslessly and the other lossy.